# Array[0] in console showing info

Tags: javascript, debugging, console, slickgrid

I am using slick grid and using a subscribed function to get notification when a cell is edited

```
grid.onCellChange.subscribe(function (e,args) {


        console.log(args);

        var a =  data[args.row];
       // var b =  args.grid.getItem(args.row);
        var c = args.item;
        console.log(a);
      //  console.log(b);
        console.log(c);

        console.log("Field Edited:"+ cols[args.cell ].field);
        $.post('action_updaterow.php',{'args[]':c},function (data){
            alert(data);
        })

    })
```

both a and c show as empty arrays in the console, however (as per picture ) when I view args in console item is displayed as an empty array but the items are shown

[image]

What does it mean when an array is listed as empty but shows values.  The real problem here is that if I pass `a`, `c` or `args.item` into my callback function teh php page doesn't recieve any data.

**UPDATE**

It turns out I structured my data in the wrong way so it was being returned as an empty Array with properties for the data.  This seems to not be understood well by anything - JSON, Jquery, console.log - I fixed the data structure to make each row an object and all is well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the `Array` is indeed empty. You can give named properties to an `Array` just like you can to an `Object`. Which means that:

```
console.log( item.CanPublish );  // "1"
console.log( item.length );      // 0
console.log( item[0] );          // undefined
```

It is generally advised not to this, as it creates confusion. JavaScript has no such thing as "named arrays". Try to stick to using *either* an `Array` *or* an `Object`.